# series convergence test with parameter

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

As part of a bigger proof I reached the series $\sum {1 \over n^\alpha}$. $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

Obviously, the convergence depends on the value of $\alpha$.

I already know the harmonic series diverges while $\sum {1\over n^2}$ converges.

How to solve the general case?

Comment: Try the integral test. It shows convergence iff $\alpha>1$.

Comment: I am not allowed to use this test (calculus I). You think I can take this assumption (converge iff $\alpha > 1$) for granted?

Comment: Well, you **must** have proved that somehow...

Comment: Is there another test to get this result?

Answer (score 1):

Some notes:

- Because $\sum \tfrac 1n$ diverges you can prove the divergence for $\alpha \le 1$ with the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test)
- Because $\sum \tfrac 1{n^2}$ converges you can prove the convergence for $\alpha \ge 2$ with the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test)
- Concerning an article I have read, you can use the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) to prove the divergence and convergence of the series.
- The function $(1,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R: \alpha \mapsto \sum \tfrac1{n^\alpha}$ is the famous [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).